# Overloading operators with dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, operator-overloading

I have a class L that takes multiple dictionaries like this:

```
L((k:'apple', y:'3', j:'4'),(k:'2', f:'12', q:'cats'))
```

I'm trying to add two D objects together and return a new L object, such that

```
a = L((k:'apple', y:'3', j:'4'),(k:'2', f:'12', q:'cats'))
b = L((n:'morapple', t:'23', f:'44'),(m:'14', n:'132', p:'morecats'))
>> a+b
L((k:'apple', y:'3', j:'4'),(k:'2', f:'12', q:'cats'),(n:'morapple', t:'23', f:'44'),(m:'14', n:'132', p:'morecats'))
c = (c:'carrot',d:'2')
>>a+c
L((k:'apple', y:'3', j:'4'),(k:'2', f:'12', q:'cats'),(c:'carrot',d:'2'))
```

I'm really lost, so far I've tried to use `eval()` with no success.. it returns nothing and I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: It looks like adding two `DL` objects is semantically equivalent to just appending the dictionaries to the list, is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

First off, stay away from `eval()` it is very, very seldom a good idea to use it.

Secondly, why can't you just do this:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if type(other) == dict:
       return DL(*(self.dicts + [other]))
    elif type(other) == DL:
       return DL(*(self.dicts + other.dicts))
    raise ValueError("Only DL and dict are supported")
```

Comment: I was so amazed when I read this!! Though, `self.dicts + other.dicts` would return as a list - our `DL` class takes `*args` and somehow needs to take comma separated dicts, this is our reasoning for using `eval()`

Comment: @unicornication: what do you mean by "comma separated" dicts? Are you storing dicts or *the string representation* of dicts?

Comment: @DanielPryden an example call would be DL(dict(blah),dict(blah), dict(blah)) - the dicts are x number of comma separated arguments using `*args`, I can't think of a way to accumulate these to pass to `DL()` - though the `self.list_of_dictionaries...` are a list of of dictionaries created once all the arguments are collected.

Comment: The constructor accepts multiple dict arguments, not a single list-of-dicts argument, so the OP needs something like `return DL(*self.dicts + [other])`

Comment: Ah, you just want `DL(*(self.dicts + other.dicts))` -- build up a list and then pass it as args. Edit: and now I see @user4815162342 just beat me to it.